# warning: ft_render: unable to set font size to 10 in Octave

Tags: cygwin, octave

I'm a new user of Octave. I tend to run some matlab files in Octave in cygwin.
It's quite useful,but it always show me that :

> "warning: ft_render: unable to set font size to 10"

. I don't know what it mean. Which kind of problem it might be?
Because of the plot function ? or I lack some packages? Does it really matter?

Thanks to everyone trying to help me!

Comment: A priori this doesn't matter since this is a warning: your code is running without error. Probably related to the plot indeed, but without your code we can't say much ...

Comment: Could you please also give the output of `graphics_toolkit` and of `version` ?

Comment: Why is this tagged as matlab?

Comment: @Ratbert Thank you for your help,my code is too long ,and it's indeed a matlab code ,I just want to run it with octave. Anyway ,thanks a lot

Comment: @patrik because my code is matblab code ,I just want to run it with octave,thank you for you concern

Comment: @ederag it's gnuplot vertion 5.0

Comment: @GQZhou I meant the output of `version` in octave command line.